How to calculate standard deviations from parts of data?
I am working with a programming API that does not correctly handle processing a lot of data. I want to calculate mean and standard deviation from 2 weeks of data by summing some (?) properties of days. My question are, which properties should I extract day by day from the data and how to "sum" them.
In the case of mean, the calculation is simple. I can take the sum of values of each day and sum of number of values of each day and divide. So in pseudocode:
count = 0
sum = 0
for i from 1 to 14:
   count = count + (GET count of day $i)
   sum = sum + (GET sum of day $i)
mean = sum / count

But as I am reading a lot of articles on Wikipedia, a similar algorithm will not work for standard deviation.
Using the API I am restricted to the following operations on data from a single day. I know I can GET: sum of all values for a single day, sum of power of 2, variance, standard deviation or getting the count of values of a single day. I currently ended with the following pseudocode to calculate standard deviation for 2 weeks, by summing variances multiplied by count every single day and dividing it by the whole count and then squaring.
$\sigma = \sqrt{ \dfrac{ \sum_{i=1}^{days}((\sigma^2)_i*n_i) }{ \sum_{i=1}^{days}n_i}}$
where $(\sigma^2)_i$ is the variance of i-th day and $n_i$ is the number of values of i-th day.
sum_tmp = 0
count = 0
for i from 1 to 14:
   count_tmp = (GET count of day $i)
   sum_tmp = sum_tmp + (GET variance of day $i) * count_tmp
   count = count + count_tmp
standard_deviation = sqrt( sum_tmp / count )

Is this correct?

Not sure this is clear.  If you are happy with your calculation of the mean, $E[X]$ then perhaps you would be happy with the computation of $E[X^2]$, and then use use the fact that $\sigma^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.
